# Minimal $k$ so that the sum of two nilpotent elements in a commutative ring is 0

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, nilpotence

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $a,b\in R$ such that $a^n=0$ and $b^m=0$ $(n,m\in\mathbb{N})$.

I proved that there exist some $k$ such that $(a+b)^k=0$ (using binomial theorem with $k=n+m$) but such derivation is not very enlightening because take $n=3,m=2$ then $(a+b)^4=a^4+4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4=0$ and $4\neq 5$.

So there's something else going on and I can't see what.

The question would be:

> What is the minimal $k$ such that $(a+b)^k=0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, $n+m-1$ is the minimum.

You can take the case $R=\mathbb Z[x,y]/\langle x^n,y^m\rangle.$

Then $$(x+y)^{n+m-2}=\binom{n+m-2}{n-1}x^{n-1}y^{m-1}\neq 0$$

Of course, it is possible in some cases for it to be smaller. If $ab=0$ then you can use $k=\max(m,n).$

If $a=-b$ then $n=m$ and $k=1.$

But the smallest $k$ which works for all rings is $n+m-1.$

Comment: This is the answer, me and a friend came up with the following solution:


Consider two baskets, each can hold $n,m$ balls respectively. If we have $n+m-2$ balls then we can have the situation where there's $n-1$ balls in one side and $m-1$ balls on the other side so the answer must be that we need $n+m-1$ balls.